# How can i set the docplex integer optimal solution tolerance

Tags: cplex, docplex

I have a problem for solving MIQCP in docplex.

The solver does not explore even though there is a better solution.

It seems to be a tolerance problem of integer optimal solution.

For example, there is an integer variable A(which is only 0 or 1, binary).

A should be 1 for minimizing the objective function, but the solution gets 0.

If A goes to 1, the objective value can be reduced by 0.027 out of 15.585.

I resolve a similar problem by setting parameters using the command,

```
    opt_mod.parameters.mip.tolerances.mipgap = 1e-100
    opt_mod.parameters.mip.tolerances.absmipgap = 1e-100
    opt_mod.parameters.simplex.tolerances.optimality = 1e-9
```

But now, the same problem has emerged again in a different situation.

What else can I adjust to solve this problem?

Now, the solve_details of my problem is like this:

```
    status  = integer optimal solution
    time    = 11.094 s.
    problem = MIQCP
    gap     = 0%
```

Thanks for your advice,

sincerely

Comment: the best bound value is also 15.585, but it should be reduced for minimize. how can i do it?